# populate dropdownlist while clicking on the edit button on datagrid view?-unable to capture the control-null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I have a gridview with employee ID and an edit button next to it. When clicking on the edit button i need to show a dropdownlist that will populate the data from db.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvEmp" runat="server" Width="100%" GridLines="Both" 
    HeaderStyle-BackColor="#999999" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    OnRowEditing="grvEmp_RowUpdating" OnRowUpdating="grvEmp_RowUpdating">

<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>
Employee Name
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
 <%# Eval("EmployeeID")%>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnLoad="DropDownList1_onload"
    onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>  
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="edit" /><br />
       </ItemTemplate>
       <EditItemTemplate>        
       <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
     </EditItemTemplate>

       </asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>

<HeaderStyle BackColor="#999999" />

</asp:GridView>
```

//Code-behind

```
protected void grvEmp_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=CHANGEME1;Initial Catalog=Reflection;Integrated Security=True");           
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select salary from employee",cn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");        //null-unable to capture the control 
    da.Fill(ds);
    cn.Close();
    ddl.DataSource = ds;
    ddl.DataTextField = "salary";
    ddl.DataValueField = "salary";
    ddl.DataBind();
    ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}
```

but when clicking on the edit button the dropdown list is not populated.
Can anyone provide an insight on this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What's the "null reference" you mention in your title? Exactly what line do you get that on?

Comment: DropDownList ddl returns null.So unable to fill the data to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the row is datarow and it is in edit mode. Your RowDataBound method should look like this:

```
protected void grvEmp_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) && ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0))
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=CHANGEME1;Initial Catalog=Reflection;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select salary from employee", cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");        //null-unable to capture the control 
        da.Fill(ds);
        cn.Close();
        ddl.DataSource = ds;
        ddl.DataTextField = "salary";
        ddl.DataValueField = "salary";
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

You should have something like this in RowEditing:

```
 protected void grvEmp_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
  {
    //Set the edit index.
    grvEmp.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    //Bind data to the GridView control.
    BindData();
  }
```

**EDIT 2 :** You should always wrap connections and dataadapters in `Using` as suggested by John Saunders in comment, which will automatically manage the lifetime of your connection and dataadapter and close/dispose when it goes out of scope.

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=CHANGEME1;Initial Catalog=Reflection;Integrated Security=True"))
{            
    cn.Open();
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select salary from employee", cn))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        ddl.DataSource =dt;
        ddl.DataTextField = "salary";
        ddl.DataValueField = "salary";
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting error Non-invocable member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType.DataRow' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Sorry, missed some `)`s. Fixed.

Comment: I would upvote you, except that the `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter` should be in `using` blocks.

Comment: But grvEmp_RowDataBound is not invoking when i clicked the edit button. Instead grvEmp_RowEditing has been invoked.